# Flexible routing in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route

I haven't used the Zend Router much yet so not sure how difficult or easy this is, but I think Zend is flexible so it's got to have a way to do this easily.

So I create a controller `Cont` with 2 actions `actone` and `acttwo`. This naturally gives me

```
//the default index controller
site.com/                
site.com/index/index     

//and my controller
site.com/cont/index
site.com/cont/actone
site.com/cont/acttwo
```

Is there a way I can access the `actone` action which is in the `cont` controller using a route that looks like this

```
site.com/actone
```

I realize I could get this look by creating a separate controller called `Actone` and this would be its `index` action but this `actone` action logically belongs to the `Cont` controller, so I want to just give the appearance of that path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom route...

Via application.ini's - Router Application Resource

```
resources.router.routes.route_title.route               = "/actone"
resources.router.routes.route_title.defaults.controller = "cont"
resources.router.routes.route_title.defaults.action     = "actone"
resources.router.routes.route_title.type                = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static"
```

Or by adding one directly to the router.

```
$router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();    
$router->addRoute('route_title', new Zend_Controller_Rotuer_Route_Static(
    '/actone',
    array(
        'controller' => 'cont',
        'action'     => 'actone'
    )
));
```

Comment: You should use Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.static) in this case to avoid firing up the regexp engine

Comment: Right.  This was just a quick example.  I'll add it in to help the next person out.

Comment: Also notable is the Jara static-route plugin (http://github.com/jara/jara-base/blob/master/library/Jara/Plugin/StaticRoutes.php).

Answer (score 2):

If you could make your `Cont` controller the default controller that would probably do the trick.  IIRC this is in Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Abstract, there's setDefaultControllerName() as well as setDefaultAction() and setDefaultModule().